# setInterval() doesn't work if a forever loop exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, replit

**Overview:** (Skip if you want)
I have basic knowledge of Javascript, I usually use javascript using node.js to code discord bots. As discord users know, discord already has bots for almost EVERYTHING. I needed some special ideas so I just decided to play around some javascript features and frameworks, hoping to get some ideas from it.

**Problem:**
I discovered a function called `setInterval(function, time)`, I was testing / playing with this function until I discovered something, here is my code:

```
console.log(`Starting interval with id: ${setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`I at this time is ${i}`)
}, [500])}`);

let i = 0;
for(;;++i);
```

I was expecting this to work but sadly it didn't. The variable `i` successfully gets incremented but the `callback of setInterval()` is never called.

My theory is that the processor is busy due to the high speed of the `for(;;++i)` so the callback doesn't get time to execute.

I tried to search about this on google, but I didn't know what to search, I even tried searching it on stack overflow but couldn't find anything.

I dont't know if this is a real question, neither do I know if this has a fix, but could someone at least tell me why this problem is occuring, am I right with my theory above?

Comment: An infinite loop just blocks the entire thread. No event will be processed until the code finishes running and it never finishes running.

Comment: In a general manner, don't block your code. You shouldn't have infinite loops or loops that takes a long time to execute. Read about how javascript works